# Making an efficient timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am trying to make a timer web app with JS, or at least doing some research before I start anyway...

The timer is essentially going to count up and be counting the time you are working on something up to 8 hours (but can potentially go into overtime).

I was thinking about using the setTimeout() or setInterval() methods but as these rely on the browser...if its a slow computer and the browser freezes for a few seconds then my timer will not be accurate over time? Am I correct in thinking this?

I was then thinking to maybe get the computer time using javascript and using that but I'm also not too sure if thats the best way to go?

I will be using jQuery a lot to build this and there are some jQuery plugins listed [here](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timer/) there I that I thought I might try but again...I'm worried about efficiency over time.

A thing that I am not really worried about is anything smaller than seconds (nanoseconds etc) although maybe I should be? lol...I havent really built anything like this before but am looking forward to the challenge!

Cheers!

Comment: If you don't trust `setInterval`, you could just save the start time in a variable and calculate the elapsed time when you need to know.

Comment: I would use chained setTimeouts and check the elapsed time for every iteration, adjusting for any discrepancies.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I like this idea! although as more of a check if I were to use setInterval...I need to show the timer counting as it is counting and I want to run an animation (just a bar filling up) as it counts...Im just thinking it could be a bit wierd if its quite a bit off for some reason, does the check and then just jumps up...